# Is there anyway to disable a submit button using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery, how to disable a submit button via its ID? I have tried many codes, but failed.

```
$("#sign_up").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

here is another one i tried:-

```
$("#sign_up").attr('disabled', true);
```

Note: I have included jquery library: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js

It will be very nice of you if you provided a fiddle :)

Comment: ... and it should suffice, unless you invoke this line _before_ `#sign_up` element appears in DOM. Is this line called in `$(function(){ ... })` block?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery documentation states that "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method." - http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-properties

`disabled` is a property and it needs to be addressed that way, using the `$(element).prop()` method. I have created a working jsFiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/tb5Xh/1/

Answer (score 0):

it should work just fine.

```
$("#sign_up").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

check the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/qb2vH/

check if you have added the jquery library correctly.

Comment: While this will work, jQuery documentation states that "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method." -http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-properties

Answer (score 0):

Users may still be able to submit forms by pressing enter in a form field.

If you want to stop the whole form being submitted, you could intercept the submit event of the form:

```
$("#sign_up").closest('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```